# About the positive integer random variable $X$ with distribution $\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)n^s}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$.For fixed $s>1$ let the random variable $X$ with $\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)n^s}$ and let $A_m:=\{{X \textrm{ is divisiable by m}}\}$
I want to calculate $\mathbb P(\frac{X}{n}=k | A_n), k >0, n\in \mathbb N$.
My attempt:

$$\mathbb P(\frac{X}{n}=k|A_n)=\mathbb P(X=kn|A_n)=\frac{\mathbb P((X=kn) \cap A_n)}{\mathbb P(A_n)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X=kn)\mathbb P(A_n)}{\mathbb P(A_n)}=\mathbb P(X=kn)$$ but this is nonsense. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by $\{{m|X}\}$ ? (you should explain your symbols as unfortunately there is not a widely accepted standardization)

Comment: X is divisible by m

Comment: $P(A , B) = P(A\ \big\vert \ B) P(B)$. Here  $\frac{(nm)^{-s}}{\zeta(s)} = P(x=nm) = P(n | x , x = nm) = P(\frac{x}{n} = m\ \big\vert \  n | x) P(n | x)$. Also $P(n | x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty P(x= m, n | x)$

Comment: Why do you assume that $\{X = kn\}$ and $A_n$ are independent events, i.e,. $$\Bbb{P}(\{X = kn\}\cap A_n) = \Bbb{P}(X = kn)\Bbb{P}(A_n)$$?

Comment: @Sangchul Indeed. that's why I wrote that my solution is nonsense

Comment: @user1952009 how does G Cab calculate something different from your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that
$$
(X = kn) \in A_{\,n} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad (X = kn) \cap A_{\,n}  = (X = kn)
$$
therefore

$$\mathbb P(\frac{X}{n}=k|A_n)=\mathbb P(X=kn|A_n)=\frac{\mathbb P((X=kn) \cap A_n)}{\mathbb P(A_n)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X=kn)}{\mathbb P(A_n)}$$

Now
$$
A_{\,n}  = \left\{ {X = jn\;\,\left| {\;j \in \mathbb N} \right.} \right\}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P\left( {A_{\,n} } \right) = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;j} {\mathbb P\left( {X = jn} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;j} {{1 \over {\zeta (s)\left( {jn} \right)^{\,s} }}} 
$$
So
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{\mathbb P\left( {X = kn} \right)} \over {\mathbb P\left( {A_{\,n} } \right)}} = {1 \over {\zeta (s)\left( {kn} \right)^{\,s} \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;j} {{1 \over {\zeta (s)\left( {jn} \right)^{\,s} }}} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {k^{\,s} \sum\limits_{1\, \le \;j} {{1 \over {j^{\,s} }}} }} = {1 \over {\zeta (s)k^{\,s} }} = \mathbb P(X=k)\cr} 
$$

Comment: looks fine to me. We are not able to simplify this equation?

Comment: @JohnDoe: added simplification, hope it is clear and useful.

Comment: @JohnDoe: is that so ?

Comment: it is all clear now I guess. Thanks for great afford!